# Map Caps+h/j/k/l to arrows respectively and Caps as change input source

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard-shortcuts

As described in the title, I would like to map <kbd>Caps</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>, <kbd>J</kbd>, <kbd>K</kbd>, and <kbd>L</kbd> as arrow keys.

Since I am not an English user, I need to change input method very often. So I want to map <kbd>Capslock</kbd> itself as change input method as well.

The OS is ubuntu 20.04 LTS.